# Starting a PHP built-in server using PHP and maintaining color

Tags: php, server, command-line-interface

I would like to start a built-in PHP server from PHP using `exec()`, `system()`  or `passthru()` for example. This works perfectly but colour codes are lost when doing so. Is there a way to maintain those colours (green/yellow/red) just like when a server is started directly from the CLI?

Comment: To confirm you're wanting the colors that you get on the CLI to also appear in your HTML output?

Comment: No, I'm talking purely about CLI output. If I start a built-in server from the CLI, successful requests are marked green, warnings yellow and errors are red. When I start a server from PHP (e.g. `exec( 'php -S localhost:8908 -t public' )`), the output in the CLI is all black. So colour codes are lost somewhere. I'm looking for a way to maintain them.